# How to format JSON response in Apps Scripts google maps geocoding

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the Google Maps geocode API working. I can't figure out how to make use of a JSON response inside of Apps Script

Here's what I have:

```
function geocode(address) {
  var options = {
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      contentType: "application/json",
  };

  var serviceUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + "address" + "&key=" + YOUR_API_KEY;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl, options);
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
WHAT GOES HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  }
}
```

How do I get the Lat Lng from this? It's been 5 hours and I can't figure it out everything just errors or returns blank entries. Any help is great.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to access the content as text and parse it as JSON. Once you have the data, you can access the latitude (`lat`) and longitude (`lng`) values from the `location` within the `geometry` field.

I am assuming that the data contains a `results` array with at least one object according to the documentation.

```js
const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

console.log(data); // View the response in its entirety

const { lat, lng } = data.results[0].geometry.location;
```

References:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#results
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response

Please read the API documentation, if you are unfamiliar with how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Google [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) class returns an [HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response) object. You can get the contents of the response data as a string with `getContentText()`

```js
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl, options);
var content_text = response.getContentText()
```

Your geocoding [response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#GeocodingResponses) will look something like but as a `string`:

```json
{
   results:[
      // some result
   ]
}
```

You can get the data by using

```js
var content = JSON.parse(content_text)
```

Each element in the `results object` will have a `geometry` key such as:

```json
{
   results:[
      {
         // some stuff
         "geometry": {
            "location": {
               "lat": 37.4224428,
               "lng": -122.0842467
         },
         // some more stuff
      }
   ]
}
```

So you can get the `lat` and `lng` of any entry with something like:

```js
var some_entry = content.results[0] // note: I'm querying the first entry, but you can use any index

var some_entry_lat = some_entry.geometry.location.lat
var some_entry_lng = some_entry.geometry.location.lng
```